# MVC - Authentication server for all projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorize-attribute

I have a solution

- API Authencation: Login, User Management... and AuthorizeAttribute: Database A
- API Resource: exp Get Products: Database B

How i can check authorize from API resource via API Authencation?

1. User login --> get Token
2. User get data from products api

[image]

Comment: Aren't there existing authentication schemes you could use? Why are you inventing something new? And what is the actual problem you're having?

Comment: in my case, API Authencation will control any request to resources. API Authentication include role and permission, exp: Role[Admin, Editor], Pemission[Product.create, Product.delete...] (like controllername.action from API resources). But, i don't understand, how i can check permission from API authentication when request API Resources from application

Answer (score 2):

I think you should used this:

JSON Web Token (JWT) is an open standard (RFC 7519) that defines a compact and self-contained way for securely transmitting information between parties as a JSON object
[JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/)

and if you using ASP.NET MVC you can try this [IdentityServer](http://identityserver.io/)

IdentityServer is Open Source OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for .NET